# Once go to login page it redirecting to the 404 page using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-7

I developed the backend function with Laravel and my URL call like https://www.exapmle.com/admin
so it will check already login means it will go to the dashboard otherwise login page https://www.exapmle.com/login it's working fine but **after login is success close the browser tab and again go to https://www.exapmle.com/login URL it's going to 404 error and if I go to this URL https://www.exapmle.com/admin it's going to the dashboard without any issue** page I don't know why it's happening please help mean to fix this issue.

Login Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/admin';
    

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    protected function logout(Request $request)
    {
        $this->guard()->logout();

        $request->session()->flush();

        $request->session()->regenerate();

        return redirect('/login');
    }

}
```

Comment: Why would you go to https://www.exapmle.com/login? You should go to https://www.exapmle.com and be redirected if you are not logged in

Comment: I looking with users side sometimes if they go to this  exapmle.com/login it will go to the 404 page it's not nice that I want to do If they already login and again they go to this  exapmle.com/login I want to redirect to dashboard

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to this issue

RedirectIfAuthenticated.php file

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        // if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
        //     return redirect('/home');
        // }
        
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) 
        {
         return redirect()->route('admin');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure because of insufficient detail maybe you have problem in your web.php. Maybe you don't have apply auth on admin route something like that